# What would be the consequences of no-void but atmosphere in space?

Tags: space, atmosphere

I was recently wondering about **atmosphere in space**.

I remember having that talk before with a friend, with one conclusion - that **it would force day in space because of the light bouncing off air particles** (sorry if the explanation does not sound too scientific) and **the visibility of far reaches of space mostly diminished** (I don't remember the explanation or if there was any). There's of course sound, but are there other consequences to be aware of?

Also: Is the void in space actually there for something? If it would disappear would it make a difference?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Questions about [third-party worlds](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/55743) are off-topic here.

Comment: The Earth revolves around the Sun, moving at a speed of about 30 kilometers per second  or about 18½ land miles per second. That is about 108,000 kilometers per hour, or about 66,600 land miles per hour. What do you think would happen if instead of moving in a nice vacuum with no resistance the Earth tried to move at that speed in a dense atmosphere?

Comment: @AlexP it would move so slow, that seasons would turn into long eras? Each Winter could mean a civilization reset?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Sorry, the Treasure Planet reference was to tell as a context, and inspiration. I'm actually trying to build a world like that, that was just the trigger. I'll remove it from the content.

Comment: I think Alex might have been referring to the atmosphere getting stripped completely from the surface of the planet, the planetary orbit slowing. The trouble with the nebular hypothesis is that space can't be full of air, because *gravity*. Could you clarify exactly what your scenario is, and what the laws of physics are in your universe that makes the scenario possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Supermassive Black Hole.**

Okay, let's run the math. Assuming Earth's atmosphere at sea level, it's about 1.2kg/cubic meter. That's not a lot of density, but let's do some *more* calculations.

For argument's sake, let's put the size of the solar system as the diameter of Neptune's orbit and stop the atmosphere beyond that (you'll see why later). That's approximately 60.1 au, or 8.996x10^12 meters (and obviously, just the average). Space is 3D, so let's take half that as *r* and do the space calculation for a sphere (4/3 * pi * r^3), or 3.81195x10^38 cubic meters. Now, our density calculation gives us a mass of a mere 4.574x10^38kg.

Now, this number isn't so easy to comprehend. It's a truly gargantuan number, but luckily astrophysics has ways of dealing with large numbers - in this case, a measurement called Mo, which is the mass in the Solar System, or *solar mass*. So, how many Solar Masses is this?

2.301x10^8. Or, in other words, *approximately 230,100,000 suns worth of mass*. Imagine a solar system with that kind of mass. The gravity at the center would collapse on itself and suck everything to the interior as a literal **supermassive** black hole. And, remember, this would apply to every single solar system - you're adding enough mass to generate a supermassive black hole for every star in the sky and that's not counting the spaces in between. The short answer is that everything turns into supermassive black holes. *Everything*.

The long answer is that eventually the mass overwhelms the supermassive black holes and they start hitting each other to ... well, no one really knows what happens to mass at that point. But at that point, there's no more atmosphere in space either.

tl;dr, gravity takes over when you put atmosphere in space and it can't stay there.

Comment: Well, one might say that my idea won't survive long in that situation :D If I'd want to do it realistically ;-)

Comment: @MauriceKlimek It's kind of hard to define realistic. And, even if you pretend that gravity doesn't exist, than the Sun would light everything on fire. And if you ignored that, than the heat would be diffracted to the point that the planets would freeze, except they wouldn't because if they kept up their rotation speed, they'd shear their surfaces to magma from the pressure, and if you slowed them down, they wouldn't orbit fast enough and fall into the Sun. See my point? Atmosphere doesn't exist in space for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

## Gravitational Collapse

The molecular clouds / stellar nurseries which form stars have a density of ~100 particles / cm^3, and occasionally, gravity will exceed atmospheric pressure triggering a collapse into stars (this has to do with a value called the Jean Limit).

The atmosphere of mars, which is 1% of Earth’s, and barely even qualifies as such, has a density of 2.6*10^17 particles / cm^3. 15 orders of magnitude higher.

Every part of your universe would simultaneously begin spontaneous collapse into black holes.